# Good Practice : Which VAE latent variable to use in dimensionality reduction

Tags: machine-learning, data-compression, digital-image-processing

I'm trying to use a VAE ([CNN-VAE](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/cvae) to be exact) to reduce the dimension of some images I have in a dataset.

I successfully trained my VAE, but now I'm not sure of the latent variable to return.

Should I use $\mu$, $\sigma^2$, or $z$ (which is sampled from $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$) ?
[image]

Thank you in advance for the advice.

Liam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest is to use $\mu$ as the output.  You could also use $z$ as the output, but that will make your dimension reduction randomized, which in some settings might be undesirable (and others might be desirable).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Do you know of any tricks to combine $\mu$ with $\sigma^2$ to get a  more significant output, or is $\mu$ usually good enough ?

Comment: @LiamF-A, I don't know; I suppose that might depend what you mean by "more significant".  This platform isn't really well suited for interactive back-and-forth or follow-up questions.

Comment: No worries, I guess I was kind of wondering if $\sigma^2$  contains any information that might be worth preserving, but I think for my purposes anyway, $\mu$ is sufficient.